# Compare SQL select and find the new records by date

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a database where every day a list of employees getting inserted. It's a SQL Server 2008. So it could be, that the list is maybe the same, but it could also be, that a new employee has been added. I do have a field with the timespamp of the day from the record, name and so on. Here is the simple select:

```
SELECT timestamp, number, rhyth 
FROM employees 
WHERE timestamp = '2020-07-13'
```

returns 853 rows

```
SELECT timestamp, number, rhyth 
FROM employees 
WHERE timestamp = '2020-07-10'
```

returns 850 rows

How do I get the 3 rows which are new between these two dates? "number" is the pkey in this case.

Comment: What if 3 new employees joined between the 2 dates?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest probably would be to use `IN`:

```
SELECT timestamp, number, rhyth FROM employees 
WHERE timestamp = '2020-07-13'
  AND number NOT IN (SELECT number FROM employees WHERE timestamp = '2020-07-10')
```

You can also use `EXCEPT`:

```
SELECT number FROM employees WHERE timestamp = '2020-07-13'
EXCEPT
SELECT number FROM employees WHERE timestamp = '2020-07-10'
```

Answer (score 1):

use left join to find out those missing rows

```
    select * from
    (
      SELECT timestamp, number, rhyth FROM employees WHERE timestamp = '2020-07-13'
    )A left join 
    (
      SELECT timestamp, number, rhyth FROM employees WHERE timestamp = '2020-07-10'
    )B on A.number=b.number where b.number is null
```

Comment: A `FULL JOIN` is better. There's no guarantee that any one table has all the employees

Answer (score 0):

How about inequalities?

```
SELECT timestamp, number, rhyth
FROM employees
WHERE timestamp > '2020-07-10' AND timestamp <= '2020-07-13'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to look for employees that did not exist before, use `NOT EXISTS`:

```
select *
from employees 
where not exists
(
  select null
  from employees before
  where before.number = exmployees.number
  and before.timestamp < employees.timestamp
)
and timestamp = '2020-07-13';
```

Remove

```
and timestamp = '2020-07-13'
```

if you don't want to restrict this to a particular date, but see all employees with their first entry.

Another option:

```
select number, min(timestamp)
from employees
group by number
--having min(timestamp) = '2020-07-13';
```